# What is the definition of Q when the discount factor depends on time?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, definitions, value-functions, discount-factor

Suppose I want to find out the Q value of a particular state $s$ bu doing action $a$ at a particular timestep $t$. I know that the Q-value when the discount factor is given by,
$$Q(a,s)=E_{\pi}\big[r_t+\gamma r_{t+1}+\gamma ^2r_{t+2}+..\big|s_t=s~~a_t=a\big]$$
If the  discount factor is not fixed, say it is  given by $\gamma(t)=e^{-t}$. Then is the Q-value given by
$$Q(a,s)=E_{\pi}\big[r_t+\gamma(t)r_{t+1}+\gamma(t)^2r_{t+2}+..\big|s_t=s~~a_t=a\big]$$ or is it given by
$$Q(a,s)=E_{\pi}\big[r_t+\gamma(t+1)r_{t+1}+\gamma(t+2)^2r_{t+2}+..\big|s_t=s~~a_t=a\big]$$

Comment: This seems similar to *eligibility traces* $e$ used in backward-mode TD learning. Basically, the $e$ values decay in time being time-dependent.

Comment: What is your motivation for having $\gamma = f(t)$, as opposed to say $\gamma = f(s)$? There are problems with definition using a function of time (independently of state - it is OK to have time as one of the properties of the state, it makes the equations work consistently), which I can go into if/when I write an answer. It would be helpful to know why you want to do this so I can suggest an alternative that may work for you